# How do I upload some special file extensions (djvu, jp2, ...) on web

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have some problems when I try to upload an image.
some extensions do not appear on the Upload Dialog, such as (.djvu, .jp2).
How do I accept that without selecting All (.)

Comment: Add more details of your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the accept Parameter like that:

```html
<input type="file" id="uploader" name="myupload" accept=".djvu, .jp2">
```

Answer (score 0):

[File inputs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file) have a parameter called `accept` where you can specifically define which file(type)s your input should handle.

You can specify either mimetypes or file extensions directly, that should help with your problem: [Unique file type specifiers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file#unique_file_type_specifiers)